# How to make statifier work on 32-bit system? error loading libc.so.6

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, static-linking, portable-executable

I've jun fresh new 32-bit ubuntu distribution and installed Statifier as usual(make all, make install). After it i tried to statify a compiled(on another device) program. After it, i've got the error message:

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path /lib /bin/ln -s /lib/libc-2.5.so /lib/libc.so.6

What actions should I do to make statifier work properly in this case?

Here is some additional error code:

```
LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=4.10.0 statifier async_record_test async_record_static
/usr/lib/statifier/32//elf_symbols: Can't open '/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3' file. Errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
/usr/lib/statifier/32//elf_data: Can't open '/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3' file. Errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
/usr/lib/statifier/32//elf_data: Can't open '/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3' file. Errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message.  And since you mentioned that it's a 32-bit system: do you think the problem is related to that?  Are you trying to statify a 64-bit program?

Comment: It was compiled on 32-bit machine

Comment: A 32-bit ARM machine, apparently?  And it looks like you're running statifier on a machine that doesn't have ARM libraries.

Comment: It's just Ubuntu 32-bit (not something with Ubuntu core i mean)
Which OS i should install to probably be able to run the program?

Comment: Ubuntu on what type of computer, though?  Different CPU architectures are not compatible with each other, even if they're both 32-bit.  It sounds like you have a program that was built on an ARM computer and you're trying to use it on something that's not ARM (probably x86).  But there's not enough detail in the question, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Wyzard my architecture is x86, but i use virtual box for the program if it matters

Comment: Well, `ld-linux-armhf.so.3` is the dynamic linker for ARM, not x86.  The program you're trying to statify is not built for x86.

Comment: Is it possible to emulate ARM somehow?

Comment: @Wyzard
root@raspberrypi:/cppcode/resources/statifier-1.7.4# ./configure 
./configure: processor 'armv7l' not supported.
Is it ok that program designed for ARM processor doesn't support armv7l?
Why don't i get same mistake on virtualbox like "processor x86 not suppored"

Comment: Because statifier supports x86 but doesn't support ARM.  And this seems to confirm what I'd guessed at earlier: you have a program compiled for an ARM CPU and you're trying to use it on an x86.  That's the kind of crucial detail that ought to be in the original question, not something that only comes out after extensive back-and-forth in the comments.